# how to my asp.net mvc website host on linux (cntose) server or this website code convert into asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

my website already host on IIS windows server. But i want to host on linux server this website code.
how to deploy my asp.net mvc website on Linux server 
asp.net code convert into asp.net core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this question, I understand that you want to migrate your present Asp.net Mvc to dotnet core App.
To do this, I am afraid you have to create a new dotnet core project and copy/paste some of your previous code in Asp.net MVC to the new dotnet core project. However, you have to do this as if you are developing a new application entirely because a lot of changes has been made in dotnet core.
let me highlight some of those changes here.

1. Asp.net is no longer using the `.Net framework` for development and deployment. it now uses a `dotnet core SDK`.
2. There is no more web.config files. we now have `appsettings.json`.
3. dotnet core uses the latest Entity Framework versions which have now changed the Identity Framework database tables name. i.e the identity tables are no longer the same.
4. Entity framework DBfirst does not include a wizard for scaffolding. you have to do it with a command.

Conclusion:
Kindly look for a quick tutorial on dotnet core and make sure you refer to the dotnet core documentation for more info.

Comment: Before you migrate from .net framework to .Net core you need to analyse Project portability and analyse the portablity of third party dependencies